# Rust Image crc32fast

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am very new to Rust. I have an issue with installing `image` crate:

```
[dependencies]
image = "0.23.14"
```

```
cargo 1.57.0 (b2e52d7ca 2021-10-21)
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version: 10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
```

I get following compiling error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for crc32fast v1.3.0
```

Probably some dependency is missing.

Comment: This error is a bit strange. After reviewing the failing build script, it appears the only thing is does is attempt to enable a compiler optimization for crc on x86 machines. Am I correct in guessing that you are not on an x86 machine?

Comment: Thanks @Locke, the reason turned out to be due to the Anti Virus

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was due to Kaspersky Anti Virus deleting the .exe file in build/crc32fast folder.

After adjusting Kaspersky I was able to compile.